# Why does GaussianProcessRegressor gives different solutions after every run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression, gaussian-process

I am working on a python code to predict data from the training set provided to fit in the `GaussianProcessRegressor`. Each time when I run the code, it results in different predicted values for the same testing data. I would like to know the reason for this behaviour and also solution to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

GP implementations contain inherently a random nature for the optimization of the model.

For a theoretical introduction you can read chapters 2 and 6 from [here](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/).

From a coding perspective, sklearn provides the [`random_state`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random-state) parameter to get reproducible results across multiple function calls.

For [GaussianProcessRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html), you can specify it via:

```py
model = GaussianProcessRegressor(random_state=42)
```